# ImportError: No module named matplotlib(I installed freetype and png)

Tags: python, matplotlib, installation

I have installed freetype and png for installing matplotlib, however 'pip3 install matplotlib' makes error. What should I do to install matplotlib..?

I just installed using 'pip install matplotlib' before, but 'import matplotlib' makes error in Jupyter notebook.

```
`
C:\Users\LeeJuyeon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32>pip3 install matplotlib
Collecting matplotlib
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ec/ed/46b835da53b7ed05bd4c6cae293f13ec26e877d2e490a53a709915a9dcb7/matplotlib-2.2.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ============================================================================
    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
                matplotlib: yes [2.2.2]
                    python: yes [3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018,
                            04:06:47) [MSC v.1914 32 bit (Intel)]]
                  platform: yes [win32]

    REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                     numpy: yes [version 1.14.5]
          install_requires: yes [handled by setuptools]
                    libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                            be found. Using local copy.]
                  freetype: no  [The C/C++ header for freetype
                            (freetype2\ft2build.h) could not be found.  You may
                            need to install the development package.]
                       png: no  [The C/C++ header for png (png.h) could not be
                            found.  You may need to install the development
                            package.]
                     qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'libqhull' could not
                            be found. Using local copy.]

    OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
               sample_data: yes [installing]
                  toolkits: yes [installing]
                     tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
            toolkits_tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]

    OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
                    macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
                    qt5agg: no  [PySide2 not found; PyQt5 not found]
                    qt4agg: no  [PySide not found; PyQt4 not found]
                   gtk3agg: no  [Requires pygobject to be installed.]
                 gtk3cairo: no  [Requires cairocffi or pycairo to be installed.]
                    gtkagg: no  [Requires pygtk]
                     tkagg: yes [installing; run-time loading from Python Tcl /
                            Tk]
                     wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
                       gtk: no  [Requires pygtk]
                       agg: yes [installing]
                     cairo: no  [cairocffi or pycairo not found]
                 windowing: yes [installing]

    OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES
                    dvipng: no
               ghostscript: no
                     latex: no
                   pdftops: no

    OPTIONAL PACKAGE DATA
                      dlls: no  [skipping due to configuration]

    ============================================================================
                            * The following required packages can not be built:
                            * freetype, png
                            * Please check http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packa
                            * ges/freetype.htm for instructions to install
                            * freetype
                            * Please check http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packa
                            * ges/libpng.htm for instructions to install png

    ----------------------------------------
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\LEEJUY~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7ifij0zf\matplotlib\

    C:\Users\LeeJuyeon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32>pip show numpy
    Name: numpy
    Version: 1.14.0
    Summary: NumPy: array processing for numbers, strings, records, and objects.
    Home-page: http://www.numpy.org
    Author: NumPy Developers
    Author-email: numpy-discussion@python.org
    License: BSD
    Location: c:\users\leejuyeon\anaconda2\lib\site-packages
    Requires:
    Required-by: tables, seaborn, PyWavelets, patsy, pandas, odo, numexpr, numba, h5py, datashape, Bottleneck, bokeh, bkcharts, astropy

    C:\Users\LeeJuyeon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32>pip show freetype-py

    C:\Users\LeeJuyeon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32>pip3 show freetype-py
    Name: freetype-py
    Version: 2.0
    Summary: Freetype python bindings
    Home-page: https://github.com/rougier/freetype-py
    Author: Nicolas P. Rougier
    Author-email: Nicolas.Rougier@inria.fr
    License: UNKNOWN
    Location: c:\users\leejuyeon\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages
    Requires:
    Required-by:

    C:\Users\LeeJuyeon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32>pip3 show pypng
    Name: pypng
    Version: 0.0.18
    Summary: Pure Python PNG image encoder/decoder
    Home-page: https://github.com/drj11/pypng
    Author: David Jones
    Author-email: drj@pobox.com
    License: UNKNOWN
    Location: c:\users\leejuyeon\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages
    Requires:
    Required-by:`
```

Comment: `pip` and `pip3` are two different programs. You should stick to one or the other. Typically `pip3` is for Python 3.x, and `pip` is for Python 2.x. Also, if you're using Jupyter Notebook provided by Anaconda, you should use their built-in module importer rather than using `pip` or `pip3`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I solved the problem by changing my python 32-bit version to 64-bit version for my 64-bit OS and installing package with [.whl] file. Have a good day.